# Authentication failing spring security wildfly

Tags: spring-security, wildfly

I am trying to migrate my spring application from tomcat to wildfly. I can't login anymore. It seems that the initial successful authentication gets lost or over written and then an anonymous session gets created.

spring security: 4.0.1.RELEASE
wildfly 8.2.0

I'm stuck, can't figure it out. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Here are the excerpts from the logs:

Successful authentication:

```
17:13:43,182 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter] (default task-6) Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fc115a3: Principal: myapp.springSupport.AccountUser@bb94ce99: Username: test1976; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_sysadmin,user; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_sysadmin, user
17:13:43,183 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler] (default task-6) Using default Url: /
17:13:43,183 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy] (default task-6) Redirecting to '/myapp/'
17:13:43,183 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (default task-6) HttpSession being created as SecurityContext is non-default
17:13:43,184 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (default task-6) SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@fc115a3: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fc115a3: Principal: myapp.springSupport.AccountUser@bb94ce99: Username: test1976; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_sysadmin,user; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_sysadmin, user' stored to HttpSession: 'io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpSessionImpl@725caa25
17:13:43,186 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] (default task-6) SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
17:13:43,202 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (default task-9) /index.jsp at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
17:13:43,202 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (default task-9) No HttpSession currently exists
17:13:43,202 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (default task-9) No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
```

Here is where the anonymous session gets created:

```
17:13:43,205 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter] (default task-9) Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
17:13:43,205 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (default task-9) /index.jsp at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
17:13:43,205 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter] (default task-9) Requested session ID 4B9EACEB7190B99CC7A1E248D8E4495B is invalid.
17:13:43,205 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (default task-9) /index.jsp at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
17:13:43,206 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (default task-9) /index.jsp at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
17:13:43,206 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] (default task-9) Checking match of request : '/index.jsp'; against '/srv/private/**'
17:13:43,206 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor] (default task-9) Public object - authentication not attempted
17:13:43,206 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (default task-9) /index.jsp reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
17:13:43,207 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (default task-9) SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
17:13:43,207 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter] (default task-9) Chain processed normally
17:13:43,207 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] (default task-9) SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
17:13:43,211 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (default task-12) /srv/home at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
17:13:43,211 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (default task-12) No HttpSession currently exists
17:13:43,211 FINE  [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (default task-12) No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
```

My spring security config:

```
<security:http auto-config="true"> 
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/srv/private/**"
        access="hasAuthority('user')"/>
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/> 
</security:http>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sooooo, I feel like a bit on a knob.

It turns out that when I use chrome and not firefox, I don't get this problem.

Firefox was mangling the JSESSIONIDs.

This is because I've been too busy working to upgrade my ubuntu and I am using a very out of date firefox browser.

Did I mention I feel like a knob?